# How does estrogen influence collagen synthesis?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, molecular-biology, endocrinology

Through what mechanisms does estrogen interact with collagen synthesis? Especially in the context of elevated estrogen levels and genesis of purpura simplex .

Comment: Questions that show no research are generally not well received in this site (they may be closed as [homework](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework)). Please see [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help) for help. The moderators are strict about effort put into research before asking a question. So please include what you found in your search for the answer in the post to get good answers.

Comment: You should look this up yourself, this is basically asking someone to do a very specific piece of reading and interpret it for you... unless you can provide some of the background info and point out points you don't understand or are interesting for discussion.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: this is a very vague question - but one that is easily addressable if you go to http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed and search for estrogen and collagen. There are numerous effects that aging and estrogens have on collagen synthesis and metabolism.